# Dragging items in gridview

Tags: android, gridview, drag-and-drop

I have a grid with a dynamic number of rows and 3 columns. Only 3 rows are visible at a certain moment. In grid I can have empty cells. Do you have any idea how to implement a drag/drop feature for the view on a view from a cell? I want to  be able to drag items in empty cells.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Comment: I need to do this in android 2.1

Comment: u want drag and drop items in empty cells

Comment: use tis link http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/10/03/drag-drop-for-android-gridview/

Answer (score 1):

Here i wish to add one more example, reference and some code snippet.

> Dragging Code
>                Let’s look at the control implementation and how we handle dragging items.
>
> ```
>         public class GridViewEx : GridView
>         {
>             /// <summary>
>             /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="GridViewEx"/> control.
>             /// </summary>
>             public GridViewEx()
>             {
>                 // see attached sample
>             }
>
>             private void GridViewEx_DragItemsStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
>             {
>                 // see attached sample
>             }
>
>             /// <summary>
>             /// Stores dragged items into DragEventArgs.Data.Properties["Items"] value.
>             /// Override this method to set custom drag data if you need to.
>             /// </summary>
>             protected virtual void OnDragStarting(DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
>             {
>                 // see attached sample
>             }
>      The control has several fields which store the indices of several active items during the drag/drop process. The OnDragStarting
> ```
>
> event stores dragged items into the
>   DragEventArgs.Data.Properties[“Items”] value. You would override this
>   method to set custom drag data if you need to.
>        When the user drags an item, we need to show hints as to where the item will be placed if dropped. The standard GridView handles this
>   by sliding adjacent items out of the way. We will implement this exact
>   behavior ourselves in GridViewEx because we need to account for cases
>   where GridView does not support dropping.
>
> ```
>     /// <summary>
>     /// Shows reoder hints while custom dragging.
>     /// </summary>
>     protected override void OnDragOver(DragEventArgs e)
>     {
>         // see attached sample }
>
>     private int GetDragOverIndex(DragEventArgs e)
>     {
>         // see attached sample 
>     }
>
>
>  Dropping Code
>  Next, let’s look at the code that handles dropping.
>  We have to override GridView.OnDrop method which is called every time when an end-user drops an item to the new location. Our override
> ```
>
> handles dropping for any ItemsPanel that the standard GridView does
>   not support dropping.
>
> ```
>  /// <summary>
> /// Handles drag and drop for cases when it is not supported by the Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.GridView control
> /// </summary>
> protected override async void OnDrop(DragEventArgs e)
> {
>     // see attached sample
> } 
>  The OnDrop method includes logic for moving items from one group to another when grouping is enabled, and for new group creation if it
> ```
>
> is requested by end-user actions.

For more details you can refer following links[Extending GridView with Drag and Drop for Grouping and Variable Sized Items](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/536519/Extending-GridView-with-Drag-and-Drop-for-Grouping)

You can follow the below link too [Android Drag and Drop Example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/drag-and-drop/android-drag-and-drop-example/)

Hope, this may help you.